# Need help in installing nightshade-11.12.1.tar.gz in my Linux Mageia?

Tags: linux, installation, mageia

I have downloaded the file nightshade-11.12.1.tar.gz from their website. I am not able to understand the installation process. Please help me how to install this software in LINUX Mageia

Answer (score 0):

I don't know nightshade, but there are three basic steps to install software from source.

After the unpacking

```
tar -xzvf nightshade-11.12.1.tar.gz
```

navigate to the new folder in your shell and use the following commands

```
./configure
make
make install
```

This will compile your sources and install the program.

You may need this from time to time, when there are no packed rpms for Mageia.

For more information:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/06/install-from-source/

http://lifehacker.com/361341/learn-the-basics-of-installing-from-source-in-linux